# Ubuntu Software app does not respond

Tags: software-center

In Ubuntu 22.04 the "Ubuntu Software" app does not open, just showing a spinning circle for a minute then nothing, no message, just nothing.
The app was showing a blank when any of the categories under the Browse tab was chosen so in Terminal I entered `snap-store --quit`, then entered `snap refresh`. The response to `snap refresh` was "snaps are up to date."
Those commands had worked before when Ubuntu Software produced a blank.  This time, just the spinning circle when I restarted Ubuntu Software.
I have several questions:

1. How do I restore the function of Ubuntu Software?
2. What is a "snap"? I was under the impression that the snap store was the equivalent of Apple's App Store, and that  Ubuntu Software was the way to access it.

Are there other ways to download, install, and uninstall software without using Ubuntu Software (which seems to be a pretty fragile app)?

Comment: You didn't restart `snap-store` . Read `man snap-store;man -k snap`. Also, please limit yourself to ONE question per Question. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: there is no man page for snap-store. How do I restart snap-store?

Comment: See https://snapcraft.io/snap-store

Comment: Are you suggesting that I re-install snap-store through the page you sent me?

Comment: I still don't understand.  How do I restart ```snap-store```?  Clearly clicking the "Ubuntu Software" icon in the Dock does not work.If restarting is through the Terminal can you please tell me the command? I am coming from Mac environment and Ubuntu Linux is pretty new to me.

Comment: Use `snap-store --help` to find out.

Comment: Waltinator comments not helpful

Comment: No. Tried most of those things without success.  It appears that the last update is responsible for the problem.  Fortunately everything can be accomplished through the command-line interface.

Comment: I would remove snap-store (ubuntu-software) and install gnome-software. I find it way more responsive and effective.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The latest update of Ubuntu 22.04 system files appears to have corrupted the "Ubuntu Software" app, but the same functions can be performed through the command-line interface in Terminal.

`snap find` produces a list of about 25 useful snaps.
`snap find <snap>` produces a list of snaps that include the named snap in either the snap name or its description.  For instance `snap find pdf` lists all the snaps related to pdf.

`snap install <snap>` installs the snap

`snap remove <snap>` removes the snap

`snap list` lists all the snaps that are already installed

`snap info <snap>` shows detailed information about snaps

`snap help --all` lists all snap commands